# Passing arguments to POST Method

Tags: html, url

Is that possible to pass arguments to a HTML form in POST method by modifying the URL? If so how can I do it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I actually need is to fill in a HTML form whose method is POST through a script. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way in which you could pass arguments to POST method in bash(command line of course). Use wget tool. example :- wget somewebsite.com/login --post-data="username=name&password=password"

Answer (score 2):

Arguments in the URL will be passed via the GET method. To pass via POST, you need to construct and post a form.

If you wish to dynamically add fields to a form, you can do this by creating a new hidden input element in Javascript and appending it to your form. JSFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E3SxH/).

Comment: What I actually need is to fill in a HTML form whose method is POST through a script. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's impossible.

The [GET](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp) method is passed via the URL. The [POST](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp) method is sent using a [form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). You can in fact use both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

no, that's not possible.

"The HTML specifications technically define the difference between "GET" and "POST" so that former means that form data is to be encoded (by a browser) into a URL while the latter means that the form data is to appear within a message body."
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com?this=that">
   <input type="text" name="textfield">
</form>
```

and retrieve the `this=that` value server-side. But generally speaking, mixing GET queries in a url with a POSTed form is generally frowned on. Especially if you've got duplicated field names in the url AND the form body.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using a javascript library, such as [jquery](http://jquery.com) but here's the old school:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fillForm() {
        document.getElementById('myText').setAttribute('value', 'some value for myText');
        // this would send the form: 
        // document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
        return true;
    }
</script>

<form method="POST" action="formHandler.php" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="myText" name="myText" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<button onclick="fillForm();">Fill it!</button>
```